# Facebook 7.0.6 for .Net Install failed

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, facebook-c#-sdk

Visual Studio 2015

Windows phone silverlight project

```
NuGet Install-Package Facebook
```

> Install failed. Rolling back... System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.GlobalPackagesFolderUtility.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.DownloadResourceV3.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageDownloader.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.d__42.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.d__42.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.d__3.MoveNext()

It did not help to run Visual Studio as an Administrator.

What could be problem?

Comment: Improved the wording of run as admin.  Added nuget tag because it is about nuget package install problem, removed c# it is nothing to do with coding in c# and implied by the fb-c#-sdk tag